# Higher input voltage to a not gate

Tags: digital-logic, not-gate

Consider a digital not gate which its input range is 5V (5V and near considered 1 and 0V and near considered 0).
What happens if we give an input of say 6.25V?

Since this is component dependent:

What happens if the gate doesn't get damaged?
Will it be turned to 0V?
What happens usually?

Comment: Hi, The result depends on the *exact* components and circuit design. Please [edit] your question to add more details and more context (and ideally also add the schematic you are considering).

Comment: It has no modulo arithmetic capability.

Comment: What does the datasheet say about it?

Answer (score 1):

Is there any specific inverter chip you are referring to?
Is that chip being powered by any specific voltage? You should be more specific in order to get a valid answer.

Depending on your circuit configuration various things could happen. A modern chip is likely to have ESD-protection diodes from the input to the supply rails of the chip to shunt any overvoltage transients that would otherwise instantly damage the chip.

If you look at the Texas Instruments CD40106 cmos inverter datasheet (just an example) https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd40106b.pdf?ts=1644554216337&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.ru%252F
You can actually see this input structure:

[image]

When you power the chip with, let's say, 5V and apply 6.25V at the input, these diodes will start conducting in an attempt to protect the input. If there is no current limiting in place the chip might very well die in the process.
If you don't kill the chip it might output '0'. But be aware you are operating the chip in undefined input areas. So nothing is guaranteed at this point. In chapter 9.2.1.2 (page 14) it is explicitly stated that the inputs must not be operated above the supply voltage for this chip.

If you feel like such a overvoltage event might happen in your application, you could try adding a large series resistance in front of the input. In that case the current is limited to a safe value if the input protection diode needs to limit the pin voltage. That's also no guarantee, the chip is just less likely to get damaged. Only assume any kind of protective effect
with this arrangement if the manufacturer states that that is alright! This is really bad practice if you ask me.

If you expect overvoltage happening, limit it with external components. Just the series resistor + internal clamping diodes is an additional safety but not a permanent solution on its own if you ask me.

Comment: For the die to be damage, the current flowing through the ESD diode has to exceed +/- 10 mA. If it's limited with a resistor, the chip will not be damage. This is a common practice for ESD protection.

Comment: I would personally not rely on the ESD diodes handling anything else than an ESD event, except when explicitly stated that it is designed to do so. The OP seems to be talking about continuous overvoltage. Since he fails to provide an actual part number for his question I would be stay on the careful side and do the clamping externally.
But your right. perhaps this is indeed being over-protective, since a milliamp or so shouldn't kill the device outright.

Answer (score 0):

If it exceeds the nominal operating range, it might not work properly.

If it exceeds the absolute maximum ratings, it can be damaged.

Comment: Thanks! Does it turn to 0 in output if it doesn't get damaged ?

Comment: You mean the output?

Comment: It wouldn't be a valid OR gate if you supplied a valid logic level but yet it did something that violated the OR logic. Having said that, if you exceed the ratings then all bets are off.